# Как читать .doc на питоне?

Tags: python, python-3.x, doc

Использую `python-docx`, но он не работает при типе файлов *microsoft word 97-2003*, так как там отсутствует *xml* содержимое. Что можно сделать, чтобы получить текст такого файла? В файле не присутствует ничего, кроме обычного текста...

Comment: А нельзя сохранить doc в docx? :) Если система на виндовс, можно так: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50796141/5909792

Comment: Нельзя, файл должен оставаться исходным. Предложенные методы по ссылке не работают

Comment: А что значит "не работает"?

Comment: связанный вопрос: [How to retrieve plain text from .doc files using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24880733/4279)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Варианты:

1. Можно посмотреть тут: [Текст любой ценой: WCBFF и DOC](https://habr.com/post/72745/).
2. Обратиться к com-объекту word. Там есть два варианта, либо забрать текст в буфер обмена и прочитать буфер в Питоне, либо сохранить как текст во временный файл и прочитать этот файл. Мы писали этот код на C++, иногда на больших объемах объект Word зависал. Кстати, можно через com-интерфейс и во временный `docx` сохранить.
3. Довольно удобен, в т.ч. и `docx` "переварит" конвертер `FileConvert.exe` от `dt_search`. Извлекается из первого пакета [тут](https://www.dtsearch.com/evaluation.html). Опять-таки сохранит текст во временный файл.
4. Использовать com-объект `IFilter`[Пример на C++](http://rsdn.org/forum/src/82418.1). Если стоит MSOffice, то соответствующий фильтр должен быть. Универсальный способ получения текста из разных форматов (если есть соответствующий фильтр), но там за "качеством" текста меньше следят, потому что он только для поиска в винде должен использоваться.
5. Использовать LibreOffice. Сам не изучал, но там, кажется, и питон хорошо подключается, и com-объект есть.

Comment: Вы подсказали интересную вещь... а ведь можно через com-объект word сохранить doc -> docx и работать уже через `python-docx`

Comment: @gil9red: если обычный текст нужен, то можно сразу как текст сохранить (`FileFormat=7`?) без промежуточного преобразования в docx.